# generate random list instead of user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently writing a program that outputs the lowest and highest numbers of an input_list.

currently I am using

```
list_of_num = [input_list for input_list in input("Input 4 numbers separated by comma's to find the lowest and highest numbers:\n").split(",")]
```

to separate the numbers input by a user, and then converting to a list to compare the numbers individually.

This is done by using:

```
maximum_output_number = list_of_num[0]

for y in range(len(list_of_num)):

    # if the other element is max then last element.
    if list_of_num[y] > maximum_output_number:
        maximum_output_number = list_of_num[y]
```

then simply printing the maximum_output_number.

so E.G. input(20,-40,-10,14.5)
would output "the highest number in the list is 20" etc.

However, I want to include the option that if a user inputs the word "generate", the program will use

`random.sample(range(-1000000, 1000000), 4)`

to generate a list and then use that generated list to output the highest and lowest numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `if-else` to check if the user inputs "generate" or not.

This should work

```py
import random
x = input("Input 4 numbers separated by comma's to find the lowest and highest numbers:\n")

if x != "generate":  #If x is not equal to generate then execute it in the normal way
    x = x.split(",")
    list_of_num = [input_list for input_list in x]


else:
'''
If x is equal to "generate" then generate a list with random values and print the
maximum of them
'''
    list_of_num = random.sample(range(-1000000, 1000000), 4)

maximum_output_number = list_of_num[0]

for y in range(len(list_of_num)):

    # if the other element is max then last element.
    if list_of_num[y] > maximum_output_number:
        maximum_output_number = list_of_num[y]
print(maximum_output_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in just a couple lines using the following:

```py
import random
ip = input("Input 4 numbers separated by comma's to find the lowest and highest numbers:\n").split(",")
max_num = max([int(ip[i]) if ip[0] != 'generate' else random.randint(-1000000,1000000) for i in range(max(len(ip),4))])
```

Example:

```
>>> ip = input("Input 4 numbers separated by comma's to find the lowest and highest numbers:\n").split(",")
Input 4 numbers separated by comma's to find the lowest and highest numbers:
4,12341,-7029704,9143750
>>> max_num = max([int(ip[i]) if ip[0] != 'generate' else random.randint(-1000000,1000000) for i in range(max(len(ip),4))])
>>> max_num
9143750
>>> ip = input("Input 4 numbers separated by comma's to find the lowest and highest numbers:\n").split(",")
Input 4 numbers separated by comma's to find the lowest and highest numbers:
generate
>>> max_num = max([int(ip[i]) if ip[0] != 'generate' else random.randint(-1000000,1000000) for i in range(max(len(ip),4))])
>>> max_num
837861
```